# How to authenticate query to my Google Sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, google-sheets-api

This is what I get from Google:

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential.

And this is what I do in code:

```
    let range = GTLRSheets_ValueRange()
    range.majorDimension = "ROWS"
    range.range = "B2"
    range.values = [["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
    let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate.query(withObject: range, spreadsheetId: SpreadSheetIdentifier, range: SpreadSheetRange)
    service.setMainBundleIDRestrictionWithAPIKey(SpreadSheetApiKey)
    service.executeQuery(query) { _, result, error in
        print(error)
    }
```

How can I authenticate my request?

Comment: Care to include where and how you get `GTLRSheets_ValueRange()`, `service`, etc? Note that an API key is insufficient authentication for writes, even to public and anonymously writable sheets. OAuth is required.

Comment: I know it;) but how to implement OAuth to write data with success? I just need public sheet and add a records visible to everyone there... without any signing.

Comment: You simply must use OAuth to authenticate the Sheets REST API. If you don't need users to do the writing, consider using a service account

Comment: Ok, I think this is what I need. How to use service account? Not asking how to create, but how to use it in my code for my needs?

Comment: That sounds like a very different question than the one asked here